# Substring Stack Split - Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string into a stack/array of string based on a regex match. The string can have [Remix Icon](https://remixicon.com/) embedded in it, that I'll extract and render HTML attributes based on the positioning.

#### Objective

The icon names will be wrapped by `:` before and after. The objective is to split strings like so:

- `"Select an option:ri-arrow-down-s-line:"` ---> `["Select an option", ":ri-arrow-down-s-line:"]`
- `"Download :ri-download-line: or upload :ri-upload-line:"` ---> `["Download ", ":ri-download-line:", " or upload ", ":ri-upload-line:"]`
- `":ri-download-line:"` ---> `[":ri-download-line:"]`

#### What's happening

I tried using `this.label.split(/:ri-.*:/)` but it doesn't include the icon names in the result stack and doesn't work with repetitions. Something like "Download :ri-download-line: or upload :ri-upload-line:" gives an output of `['Download ', '']` with this.

- Improvement 1: Using `/:ri-[^:]*:/` improves the string splitting, and accounts for repetitions. However now I need to figure out how to include the matched regex in the stack at the respective positions

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use capturing group in split `/(:ri-[^:]+:)/` to be included into the result, then you might have to filter empty elements from the split result:

```js
const Split = s => s.split(/(:ri-[^:]+:)/).filter(Boolean);

console.log(Split("Select an option:ri-arrow-down-s-line:"))
console.log(Split("Download :ri-download-line: or upload :ri-upload-line:"))
console.log(Split(":ri-download-line:"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple refex to do the splitting:

```
/(?=:ri)/g
```

It simply splits whenever there's `:ri` to the right.

Note it uses the `global` flag so it can match and split on all occurences.

Now you have an array. If you want the syntax shown in your question, you can use `JSON.stringify` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting on 1, it could be matching both.

For example:

```js
const label = "Download :ri-download-line: or upload :ri-upload-line:"

let arr = label.match(/(:ri-[^:]*:)|[^:]+/g);

console.log(arr);
```